# Word: can I split the cells of a table to different rows?

Tags: microsoft-word

In the word document, I have a table of 1 row x 2 columns. I want to split the 1st column into 2 rows and the 2nd column into 3 rows. But I cannot do that. The table in the Word has to be aligned.

Of course, I can firstly prepare a table of 6 row x 2 columns, then merge them.

But is there a quicker way?

Comment: Right click on the table (particular cell) and click on `Split Cell` and specify the rows / columns you want to split them

Comment: @Prasanna, I tried, I can split the first column into 2 rows. But when I split the second column into 3 rows, I was told: "The number must be between 1 and 2".

Comment: The other workaround I do is, I create all my tables in Excel and paste them in Word. Is that option available for you?

Comment: @Prasanna, thank you. I can use Excel. But as I said, I cannot have 2 rows and 3 rows in the same time. I have to use 6 rows first, then merge them into 2 rows and 3 rows.              I use 2 rows and 3 rows as an example, but I actually have 5 rows and 6 rows to tabulate. So I have to prepare 30 rows first, then merge them.